# Nightwatch cucumber generate static html report

Tags: nightwatch.js, cucumberjs

I'm trying to generate a report on nightwatch cucumber using `nightwatch-html-reporter` but I'm not able to make it work.

The library I am using is [Nightwatch html Reporter][1], I followed the steps described but I'm getting the error when reading the reports directory:

```
Reading reports directory...
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

Comment: Please explain what you have already attempted.

Comment: @ChathurangaChandrasekara refrased the question

Comment: Maybe you are not setting correctly the path of the cucumber report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct configuration would be:

Create file in root tests, same level of package.json.

```
var reporter = require('cucumber-html-reporter');

var options = {
    theme: 'bootstrap',
    jsonFile: 'reports/cucumber.json',
    output: 'reports/index.html',
    reportSuiteAsScenarios: true,
    launchReport: false
};

reporter.generate(options);
```

And configure runner in package.json. Example:

```
"scripts": {
    "e2e": "npm-run-all test report --continue-on-error",
    "test": "nightwatch",
    "report": "node create-html-report.js"
}
```

Make sure it is set up this way, or enter more details of the error.